# Preact: How to properly code split pre-rendererd components using dynamic import?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preact, code-splitting

**Backstory:**
I'm working on a codebase which is primarily Python with Jinja templates because the site is mainly static. However, for interactive components we're using Preact to pre-render the components and then re-hydrate them if they're found on the page.

**Example:**
We create a bookmark component that is only used on 5 out of say 100 pages. This should be code split so that itself and other components in similar situations aren't added into the main bundle.

This bookmark component is pre-rendered and added into the python codebase.

**In Preact:**

```
import Bookmark from './Bookmark'

const bookmark = document.querySelector('.bookmark')
if (bookmark) {
    hydrate(<Bookmark/>, bookmark);
}

const App = () => {
  // call effects here.

  // returns nothing because all components are pre-rendered.
  return <div/>
}
```

One way that I've been successful is by changing this to use dynamic import:

```
const bookmark = document.querySelector('.bookmark')
if (bookmark) {
    import('./Bookmark').then(module => {
     const Bookmark = module.default;
     hydrate(<Bookmark/>, bookmark);
    });
}
```

This works but I'm not able to find a single example saying this is how you should handle code splitting in an application that isn't primarily driven by React. Does anyone know if this if this is the proper way to handle this?

Also, a note on why I'm not using lazy or suspense. If you look in my example we're only hydrating we're not rendering into a full preact application. This is just a sprinkle of interactivity. We could use lazy by itself but that was causing an error to throw because I didn't need the suspense component.

Any advice around this topic would be greatly appreciate. The final goal being to reduce the main bundle size by removing non-global components from the main bundle.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think your solution works fine. Frameworks like Next.js and Gatsby are working on this by integrating Partial Hydration with help of React Server Components but this is really new. 
The way you are doing seems fine because in your case you still have static site generation and you hydrate with JS on page load so the performances should be alright. Also components are cached between pages (since each component dynamic import generates a JS chunk).

Comment: adriendenat, Thanks for commenting! I agree that this seems like the way to go but was curious if anyone else was having a similar problem. I will look into next js and gatsby to try to learn about more use cases with server rendered components.

Comment: React Server Components are very much their own thing, requiring frameworks to build around them and their runtime. Preact does not, and likely will not, support them due to the large cost and uncertainty compared to existing and proven partial hydration techniques. Astro and Deno Fresh are two frameworks that support Preact, they might be a good reference point.

Comment: rschristian, yeah I totally agree they shouldn't support this because this is sort of going against the grain of what preact does out of the box. This project is one where I don't have control of the stack. So, I'm just trying to see if anyone else has been in this situation and could advise. I have tried out astro and really liked it. I will see if anything they're doing would apply to my situation great point!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my preact web app. Using the lazy allowed me to do the dynamic import for code splitting the route.

```
import { LocationProvider, Router, Route, lazy } from 'preact-iso';
const MyLazyRoute = lazy(() => 
    import('./pages/myLazyPath').then(module => 
        module.myLazyPath));

export function App() {
    return  (
        <LocationProvider>
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/lazy-path" component={MyLazyRoute} />
            </Route>
        </LocationProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your entry point file, import `lazy` and `Suspense` from `preact/compat`:

```js
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import { lazy, Suspense } from 'preact/compat';
import Router from 'preact-router';

// Dynamically import Home and Browse components
const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const Browse = lazy(() => import('./routes/Browse'));

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Router>
                    <Home path="/" />
                    <Browse path="/browse" />
                </Router>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

In this code, `lazy` is used to dynamically import the `Home` and `Browse` components. The `Suspense` component provides a fallback UI (`<div>Loading...</div>`) while the `Home` and `Browse` components are loading.